# The mean of Langevin equation

Tags: statistical-mechanics, differential-equations, statistics, brownian-motion, stochastic-processes

I have a very basic question regarding the mean of the Langevin equation. 
So we have an equation of the form:
$$\dot{v}(t)=-\beta  v(t)+ \xi (t)$$
Where $\xi (t)$ is a Gaussian white noise with an average zero and a $\delta$ correlation in time.
As known, this equation has the following solution:
$$v(t)=v(0) e^{-\beta t}+\int_0^t dt' e^{-\beta (t-t')} \xi(t') $$
and I want to take the mean of this equation, i.e., $\langle v(t)\rangle$
The second term goes is zero since $\langle\xi (t)\rangle=0$, which leaves the first term. This, according to some books I have been reading, should be: 
$$\langle v(t)\rangle=v(0) e^{-\beta t},$$
 but I really don't get how we got this result? It's a bit confusing to me.

Comment: Doesn’t it just follow from your equation?

Comment: Are you asking how the solution $v(t)$ is derived? Or the mean of the solution reduces to the first term of the solution?

Comment: How does it follow from my equation? it's just not my brightest day today lol

Comment: How the mean of the solution reduces to the first term..

Comment: Well you state it in the post itself: $\xi$ is a Gaussian random variable with mean zero, so the mean of $v(t)$ reduces to what's left: $v(0)\exp(-\beta t)$.

Comment: Also, if you want to reply to someone, use `@username` in the comment (e.g., `@kylekanos` for me) and it will send them an alert that you replied.

Comment: @KyleKanos thanks for the answer, but why does it reduce to the first term? is it because we are taking the mean in terms of t' ? because I tried to do it first and I thought I have to consider the first term as a negative exponential distribution, and the mean of that is definitely not the function itself.

Comment: It follows from the statement *ξ(t) is a Gaussian white noise with an average zero* in the post. To be more clear, that italicized statement is saying $\langle\int\mathrm dt'e^{-\beta(t-t')}\xi(t)\rangle\equiv0$.

Comment: @KyleKanos Thanks! butThis is already clear to me that the mean of the gaussian noise is zero, but how is $\braket{v(0) e^{-\beta (t)}$=$v(0) e^{-\beta (t)}$ ? is it because we are considering it as a constant ?

Comment: The second term in your solution contains $\xi(t)$ or $\xi(t')$ in the integrand?

Comment: @VladimirKalitvianski it's $\xi (t')$ of course, sorry for the confusion..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let me answer the original question as I understood it literally. It has a methodological value.

I understand taking a mean value as some integration over a limited period $T$: $$\langle f(t)\rangle=\frac{1}{T}\int_t^{t+T}f(\tau)d\tau$$ Only doing this we may "eliminate" the fluctuating force $\xi(t)$. Now, applying this averaging to the solution $v(t)$ we obtain: $$\langle v(t)\rangle=\frac{1}{T}\int_t^{t+T}v(0)\text{e}^{-\beta \tau}d\tau + \frac{1}{T}\int_t^{t+T}\text{e}^{-\beta \tau}d\tau\int_0^{\tau} dt' \text{e}^{t'} \xi(t')$$ Now let us take the first integral: $$\frac{1}{T}\int_t^{t+T}v(0)\text{e}^{-\beta \tau}d\tau=v(0)\frac{\text{e}^{-\beta t}(1-\text{e}^{-\beta T})}{\beta T}$$ This is an exact result of our averaging over some period $T$. Now, if inequality $\beta T\ll 1$ holds, in the first approximation the difference in the nominator is equal to $\beta T$ with a good precision, thus you obtain the answer to the original question.

In order to make sure that the second term in the exact solution vanishes after averaging, you must respect - in addition! - another inequality, namely $T/\delta\gg 1$. Otherwise some "long-time" fluctuations will still be present in the mean solution. I leave the proof of this as an exercise to those who downvoted my answer without explanation.

Finally, let me note that although the noise force mean value is zero, it does not mean that this force does not displace the particle in the space. Originally still particle ($v(0)=0$) and without friction ($\beta=0$) may be found elsewhere: $x(t)=\int_0^t dt'\int_0^{t'}\xi(t'')dt''\ne x(0)$, remember the Brownian motion, for example. Another (funny) example: a periodic external force $F(t)=F_0\cdot \sin(\omega t)$. On average this force is zero, but it displaces the particle with time far far away ;-)  One cannot obtain this result by just dropping out this force from the exact equation of motion.

**EDIT:** As pointed out Alexander in his comment, "*Langevin equation is about stochastic processes. Averages of stochastic processes are (usually) with respect to different noise realizations (all taken from same distribution). In different language - tracing out the ensemble of stochastic environment.*" In other words, averaging is done in fact over some parameter independent of time. It is like averaging over a random initial phase $\varphi_0$ in my last example with a periodic external force $F_0\cdot\sin(\omega t + \varphi_0)$. Thus, it is not averaging the equation or its solution over $t\le\tau\le (t+T)$. Although mathematically it is possible, I do not fully understand how it may naturally arise in physical calculations and what meaningful conclusion one can draw from such averaged things.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question.

Comment: Please, define what is meant by taking the mean value explicitly. Is it an integration over a finite period?

Comment: Langevin equation is about stochastic processes. Averages of stochastic processes are (usually) with respect to different noise realizations (all taken from same distribution).In different language - tracing out the ensemble of stochastic environment.

Comment: @Alexander: Thus, averaging is done in fact over some parameter independent of time. I was mislead by the $\delta$ as a time constant in the time-dependent force $\xi(t)$.

Answer (score 1):

To see why the first is left when taking the mean, re-write the SDE as,
$$
\mathrm dv=-\beta v\mathop{}\!\mathrm dt+g(x,\,t)\mathop{}\!\mathrm dW,
$$
where $g(x,\,t)$ is some function and $\mathrm dW$ the stochastic noise. Then we can obtain a differential equations for the mean of $v$ by taking the mean of both sides:
$$
\mathrm d\langle\mathrm v\rangle=\langle\mathrm d v\rangle =\langle -\beta v\rangle\mathop{}\!\mathrm dt
$$
since $\beta$ is a constant and $\langle\mathrm dW\rangle=0$. This can be rearranged to,
$$
\frac{\mathrm d\langle v\rangle}{\mathrm dt}=-\beta\langle v\rangle,
$$
the solution of this differential equation should be immediately seen:
$$
\langle v(t)\rangle=e^{-\beta t}\langle v(0)\rangle
$$
which matches the sources you've seen, aside from the lack of $\langle \cdot\rangle$ wrapping $v(0)$, which I suspect is some level of your confusion (the other bit being the exponential being dependent on $t$, though this confusion should be cleared up from the derivation above).

Comment: Actually you solve another equation- your second one, which you postulate rather than derive; thus it has a limited relation to OP question.

Comment: @VladimirKalitvianski my Eq 2 is derived from Eq 1, which isn't exactly the same as OPs but has the same deterministic part which is the important part in the mean. Don't be so upset that your answer isn't well received that you "take revenge" on a better answer.

Comment: You too, don't be upset that your answer is not the right one. You do not derive the second equation!

Comment: @vlad I suppose you're right in that I don't *derive* it, it just follows from the text (i.e., applying averages). I think your answer still overcomplicates the matter compared to mine, but it is significantly better now that you've fleshed out *why* the decaying matters (instead of your simply asserting that's the reason). I'm going to remove the "edit" market in your post, though, because SE tracks edits and those interested can just click the edit history to see what changed.

Comment: With removing some parts of my text, you violate my authorship. In addition it makes the paragraphs somewhat inconsistent. I disagree with such a practice.

Comment: @vlad it absolutely does **not** violate your authorship. Note that your posts are licensed under Creative Commons, so anyone can edit it freely (see more https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing). If you have issues with that, then you shouldn't be posting on such a framework as this site (though I'd be sorry to lose a contributor as you).

Comment: Yes, it violates my authorship and the meaning of my answer. Editing should not have such an effect. I will modify my answer in order to be consistent with OP.

Comment: @vlad I think you need a better understanding of the CC license.

Comment: 'd better be happy with your own answer.